# Mocking a blackberry call

Tags: testing, blackberry, java-me

I am working on a blackberry application in which I have a phone listener that checks for stuff like incoming calls, dropped calls etc. and does some action according to this. I want to test that everything is working correctly so I am looking ways of mocking, for example, an incoming call or a dropped call. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: The simulator allows you to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would write unit tests with `junit` and `mockito`:

```
public class CallRegistrator implements PhoneListener {
   private final CallLogPersistence persistence;
   public CallRegistrator (CallLogPersistence persistence) {
      this.persistence= persistence;
   }
   ...
}

public class CallRegistratorTest {
   CallLogPersistence  persistence = mock(CallLogPersistence.class);
   CallRegistrator registrator;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      registrator = new CallRegistrator(persistence);
   }

   @Test
   public void whenCallFinishedItIsRecoreded() {
      int id = 1;
      registrator.callDisconnected(1);

      verify(persitence).saveFinishedCall(id); 
   }
}
```

There are also possibility to have automated acceptance test with simulator. It has possibility to simulate incoming call.